# Maximum Likelihood Estimate and Second derivative test?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

We're doing MLE's in my prob stats class currently, and my professor insists that after we get the derivative of the Ln of L we still need to take the second derivative to check if it's the MLE. My book however says that the derivative of the Ln of L is always the MLE. He refuses to let us skip this step without a Theorem/proof for this, but I can't find one. Can anyone point me towards one, or correct me if our book is wrong?

Comment: Strictly speaking, showing that the gradient of the log likelihood vanishes does not show that the point in question is a maximum of the log likelihood. You could try to argue that it is in general concave, but if you don't have that theorem at your disposal then you have to check it separately.

Comment: @Ian Interesting. Everything I've been reading that the graphs of Ln of L and just L maximize the same and that we can just take the first derivative to get the maximum for L. Strange all these schools are posting this without it being a true fact.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me. $\log$ is a strictly increasing function, so a point is a maximizer (resp. minimizer) of $L$ if and only if it is a maximizer (resp. minimizer) of $\log(L)$. But a point is not necessarily a maximizer simply because the gradient vanishes there. Now perhaps the likelihood is somehow guaranteed to ensure concavity...but that is not free. If it is true (and I doubt that it is, in full generality) then it requires proof.

Comment: @Ian makes sense, I feel like if it is true if I keep digging I'll find a proof as every textbook and lecture notes from every college I can find online says the same thing...

Comment: "My book however says that the derivative of the Ln of L is always the MLE" I doubt that. A screenshot?

Comment: This actually is false.  the MLE is not always the derivative of the log of the likeliehood.  Examples abound where this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MLE is simply the global maximum of a  function (the likelihood , as a function of the parameter ): $L(\theta)$

You are supposed to know, not from Statistics but from Calculus, that, in general, the global maximum of a function cannot simply be found by deriving the function and equating it to zero. That only gives as a  critical point (perhaps several). It can well happen that

1. the function is not derivable in some points of the domain
2. the (some) critical point is not a maximum
3. the global maximum occurs on the boundary of the domain

The estimation of an uniform variable on $[0,\theta]$ is an example of the last situation.

Granted, if you know that

1. $L(\theta)$ is derivable in all its domain
2. there is a single critical point
3. the domain of the parameter is the whole real line
4. $L(\theta)$ tends to zero at $\pm \infty$

then you know that the critical point is the MLE. If you know the first 3 conditions but not the fourth, then you should compute the second derivative.
If you only know $1.$ and $2.$ then you should also check the boundaries of the domain.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but is "derivable in all its domain" the same as "differentiable for every point in the domain?"